# HOWTO toggle working between multiple dev machines on same repo in perforce

Tags: git, perforce

I am new to perforce. I wanted to know the best approach for toggling of work between your workstation and laptop? E.g. if I am working on something on my workstation & then leave for a weekend & then want to continue working on my laptop, how do folks go about doing it?

Giving example of git, I could just do,

```
# On my Workstation
git commit -am "Time to go home"
git push origin local-wm:local 

# On my Laptop
git fetch origin
git checkout local-lm
git merge origin/local
```

That's it. It doesnt matter if I have changed files, renamed files, added files or deleted files. It just works.

The closest to this I could do on perforce using `p4v` (with lot of hiccups) was,

1. On workstation, select files you might want to work on from your `default` changelist & move it to a new changelist
2. Once new changelist is created, select it & then shelve files
3. On my laptop refresh p4v
4. Select the changelist created in workstation & then unshelve files

This is the happy path. But then there are complications when you do this back & forth couple of times and,

- You have already checked out files which are new additions in your laptop, which are then also present in the sync-changelist
- You rename the file in workstation, then it will show up as a new file when you unshelve it on your laptop

Also seemingly you have to create 2 distinct changelists one for syncing from your laptop to workstation AND other to sync changes from workstation to laptop.

Hopefully folks have faced this & have better approach then this. I am totally up for a command line driven approach as well (in fact it's much better that way).

Comment: Do you have to use Perforce? There's a reason Git has become nearly ubiquitous.

Comment: @ACVM looks like it, at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a private branch/stream so that you can submit work-in-progress, not affect the shared main branch, but still keep everything versioned and merge-able with anything else you're doing.

```
# On my Workstation
p4 submit -d "Time to go home"

# On my Laptop
p4 sync
```

Shelves are good for one-offs but it sounds like you're pretty far past their limit of usefulness if you have a bunch of them swirling around.  Most of Perforce's power with respect to syncing and merging requires that you submit your changes somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, Sam I will check this out.